# How can you put a cooldown between clicks with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, click, mouse

So, for example, if you did `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);` -- How would you be able to set a... let's say 5 second cooldown, so you'd have to wait 5 seconds before it would allow you to click again? Or at least run the onClick function.

Answer (score 2):

Option #1 :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    }, 5000);
}
```

Option #2 :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
var then:int = 0;
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
    var now:int = getTimer();
    if(now - then > 5000) {
       // do your thing
       then = now;
    }
}
```

Option #3 :

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000, 1);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
private function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{   
   stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
   timer.start();  
} 

private function onComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
{ 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
    timer.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have handled this problem is to create a global TouchManager. I hate global objects in practice, but, in some cases, they address the problem well. In this case, a global makes sense because, for my purposes, I want all touch input from all possible sources to be disabled.

Within my TouchManager, there is a static function which allows any caller to suspend touchability on a timer, among other things. In my implementation, I would call this function with a timeout of 5 seconds. Then, any event handler which processed touch input would consult with the TouchManager and return out of the handler prematurely if touch handling was currently suspended.

Cue the "if something is called a manager you are doing it wrong" crowd.